# Direction of the frictional force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Why is it said that friction always acts in the direction opposite to the relative motion at the point of contact with the surface?
When a sphere is rolling down an incline for example, the friction acts upwards in order to create a torque which increases the sphere's angular velocity to prevent rolling without slipping. The thing is, the relative motion between the point of contact and the sphere is also upwards.[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the sphere is rolling without slipping there is **no relative motion** between the sphere and the surface at the point of contact.

The ball "wants" to slip, such that there will be a relative motion between the surfaces however what prevents this slipping is the static friction force, acting against the potential direction of motion.